# remove dictionary quotation from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, file, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Below is the output of my dataframe:

```
              0                                  1  
0  {"time": "2016-03-28T23:23:12Z"      "target": "Raffi-Antilian"}  
1  {"time": "2016-03-28T23:23:12Z"      "target": "Caroline-Kaiser"}
```

How can I convert individual records from type dictionary to normal dataframe records with columns names being dictionary keys and record values being dictionary values? My desired output should be:

```
              Time                Target  
0  2016-03-28T23:23:12Z      Raffi-Antilian   
1  2016-03-28T23:23:12Z      Caroline-Kaiser
```

I have about 2000 records, Appreciate any help/guidance.

Comment: How are you getting your data into the dataframe?  That's the step where this issue should be addressed.

Comment: @root looks like the repr of a dict or json, split by `,`... but yeah... completely agree :)

Comment: @root i am getting it through a .txt file  using pd.DataFrame.from_csv command. In the .txt file individual records are encapsulated within a dictionary and there is no separator between records (for eg {'time': XX, 'Target': YY}{'time': VV, 'Target': ZZ} ).

Comment: Can you please add the code you used to load this and some example data?

Comment: @SirajS.: Could you please provide a sample snippet of your text-file and of the code you already have?

Comment: look  at StringIO on importing text.

Comment: @albert here is my code: 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(path,header=None,index_col=None)

here is the snippet of the text file data:
{"time": "2016-03-28T23:23:12Z" , "target": "Raffi-Antilian"} {"time": "2016-03-28T23:23:12Z", "target": "Caroline-Kaiser"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `sep=';'` if in file is **not** `;`, so all data are in one `Series`. Then convert `string` to `dictionary` by `ast.literal_eval` and last use `pd.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
import io

temp=u"""{"time": "2016-03-28T23:23:12Z","target": "Raffi-Antilian"}  
{"time": "2016-03-28T23:23:12Z","target": "Caroline-Kaiser"}"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
s = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), index_col=None, header=None, sep=';', squeeze=True)
print (s)
0    {"time": "2016-03-28T23:23:12Z","target": "Raf...
1    {"time": "2016-03-28T23:23:12Z","target": "Car...
Name: 0, dtype: object

L = s.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)).tolist()
print (L)
[{'time': '2016-03-28T23:23:12Z', 'target': 'Raffi-Antilian'}, 
 {'time': '2016-03-28T23:23:12Z', 'target': 'Caroline-Kaiser'}]

print (pd.DataFrame(L))
            target                  time
0   Raffi-Antilian  2016-03-28T23:23:12Z
1  Caroline-Kaiser  2016-03-28T23:23:12Z
```

EDIT:

Another one line solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

print (pd.DataFrame([json.loads(line.strip()) for line in open('file.txt')]))

            target                  time
0   Raffi-Antilian  2016-03-28T23:23:12Z
1  Caroline-Kaiser  2016-03-28T23:23:12Z
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import json
data = []
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

gives

```
Out[49]: 
            target                  time
0   Raffi-Antilian  2016-03-28T23:23:12Z
1  Caroline-Kaiser  2016-03-28T23:23:12Z
```